# How do I move code to a worker when it depends on code outside of the worker?

Tags: node.js, heroku, worker

Running a node.js app that has various components that are required in the main `index.js` file, like this:

```
// index.js

require('./component-1.js')
require('./component-2.js')
require('./component-3.js')
// ...etc.

yield App.init()
```

Basically, by `require`ing those components, they attach themselves to the `App`, and I can reference `component-1` inside of `component-2`.

The problem is that `component-2` does a lot of tasks that take a lot of time to complete (minutes to hours). So, I want to move `component-2` to a separate worker. With Heroku I would do this in the Procfile (telling it to spin up a separate dyno):

```
# Procfile
worker: node ./component-2.js
```

Problem: `component-2` depends on `component-1` having been registered with the `App`. Therefore if I want to run `component-2` as a worker, I'll have to register `component-1` inside the worker as well.

One solution I tried was to basically spin up a "mini app" inside the separate worker:

```
// workers/worker.js

require('component-1')
require('component-2')

yield App.start()
```

Then do `worker: node workers/worker.js` inside my Procfile, but now any time I want to extract a component into a worker, I have to track down every single other component it depends on, and move them into the "mini app".

Any other good solutions for this?

**Edit**

To clarify, both the main `App` and `component-2` depend on `component-1`, but `App` doesn't care about `component-2`.

Comment: `minutes or hours` exactly what is this component doing ? works with database ? too many async calls? does App requires the component 2 to be ready so it can not fail ?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix it's a long-running data aggregation process (yes, partially works with 2 dbs, postgres and mongodb). I could move component-2 to a separate worker and the main App would not fail, but I would also need to move component-1 to both the worker *and* keep it inside the App, since component-2 needs component-1, and App also needs component-1.

Comment: I see component1 as the common point in your application, it would be better if your run it a separate service and have component 2 and App communicate with it  see Seneca microservices, senecajs.org using plain TCP.